Is there a way to define a generic type generically?
If I want to implement a struct with a certain generic type that requires alot of traits, like below. I then have to copy this to every time i implement a trait for this struct (where it needs the same type) is there a shorthand way to do this? I am imagining something like generic T = Add + ... + PartialEq
impl<T> FOO<T>
where
    FE: Add
        + Copy
        + ...
        + Debug
        + PartialEq,

I've tried looking for this on the web to no avail, however I am also very new to rust so it may be obvious, sorry if this is the case.

You can create a new trait, which has all your required traits as supertraits, and then use blanket implementation. For example:
trait Combined: Copy + Clone + Debug + Display /* add how many of these you want */ {}

impl<T> Combined for T where T: Copy + Clone + Debug + Display {}

struct Foo<T: Combined>(T);

impl<T: Combined> Foo<T> {
    //
}

Note however, that it is idiomatic to leave trait bounds when declaring structs (unless you have to name associated types of those traits), and only put bounds on impl blocks. Still this technique allows to greatly simplify naming complex bounds.

For that note: do you mean it'd be more idiomatic to write just struct Foo<T>(T)?

@yshavit Yes. And put Combined bound on T in generic impl block.

Cool, thanks! I didn't know that (hazards of self-learning, it's easy to miss on idioms)

@yshavit Ha, I've killed two birds with one stone then. :) For examples of that, look at standard library. For example Cell<T> doesn't have Copy bound on T,  only on impl block defining get. So you can create Cell with T: !Copy, but you couldn't then call get on it. This pattern is common is standard library.

@AleksanderKrauze Yeah, it makes total sense. I just never noticed it before. :-D
